# How to fill data gaps with random coordinates from a polygon?

Tags: polygon, r-sf, spatial-data-frame, spatial-data

I have a data set of whale sightings with some coordinate gaps but associated with areas of reference, of which I have coordinate limits. I've used these limits to create a polygon restricted to the marine environment (using library ‘sf’) for each of the areas. Now I would like to fill the coordinate gaps by randomly selecting latitudes and longitudes from the polygons.

My piece of code (example for the area 'Angola'):

`#Creating a ocean-only polygon for the Southern Hemisphere (my study area)`

`x_coord = c(180, 180, -180, -180)`
`y_coord = c(0, -90, -90, 0)`

`polygonSH =  cbind(x_coord, y_coord) %>%`

`st_linestring() %>%`
`st_cast("POLYGON") %>%`

`st_sfc(crs = 4326, check_ring_dir = TRUE) %>%`

`st_sf()`

`land = rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") %>%`

`st_union()`

`ocean = st_difference(polygonSH, land)`

`plot(st_geometry(land))`
`plot(st_geometry(polygonSH), add = TRUE)`
`plot(st_geometry(ocean), add = TRUE, col = "blue")`

`#Creating ocean-only polygons for each of the different areas to then use them in the arguments to run ramdon coords`

`#Angola`

`x_angola = c(11.72,11.72,13.58,13.58) #longitude limits of Angola area`

`y_angola = c(-12.34,-16.6,-16.6,-12.34) #latitude limits of Angola area`

`polygon_angola = cbind(x_angola, y_angola) %>%`

`st_linestring() %>%`
`st_cast("POLYGON") %>%`

`st_sfc(crs = 4326, check_ring_dir = TRUE) %>%`

`st_sf()`

`plot(st_geometry(land))`

`plot(st_geometry(polygon_angola), add = TRUE)`

`angola_ocean = st_difference (polygon_angola, land)`
`plot(st_geometry(angola_ocean), add = TRUE, col = "pink")`

...

Before having the polygons restricted to the marine environment, I've used the code below to randonmly generate the coordinates, and ideally I would like to use something similar, but adjusted to working with spatial data:

for(i in 1:dim(x)[1]) {

x[i,"lat"] <- ifelse(is.na(x[i,"lat"]) && x[i,"area"]=="Angola", runif(1,-16.6,-12.34), x[i,"lat"])

x[i,"long"] <- ifelse(is.na(x[i,"long"]) && x[i,"area"]=="Angola", runif(1, 11.72,13.58), x[i,"long"])

}

I would really appreciate having folk's input on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your code to work due to issues (invalid spherical geometry) not directly related to the subject of the question.

So please allow me to illustrate a possible approach using the well known & much loved North Carolina shapefile that ships with the `{sf}`.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)


# included with sf package
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
  summarise() # a single polygon 

# now the action! 50 random points over North Carolina
random_points <- shape %>% 
  st_sample(50)

# check results...
plot(shape)
plot(random_points, col = "red", pch = 4, add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jindra. I was having issues using the st_sample function, but after downloading different versions of R and RStudio, it finally worked and I could proceed as you suggested. The step is then sorted, but I still having issues when trying to get coordinates from the samples to fill the gaps in the data frame.

Comment: I'm trying "angola_points = st_sample(angola_ocean, 50)" and then "for(i in 1:dim(x)[1]) {
  
  x[i,"lat"] <- ifelse(is.na(x[i,"lat"]) && x[i,"area"]=="Angola", sample(angola_points$lat,1), x[i,"lat"])
  
  x[i,"long"] <- ifelse(is.na(x[i,"long"]) && x[i,"area"]=="Angola", sample(angola_points$lon,1), x[i,"long"])
  
}" and it runs, but coordinates are out of the area delimited for the coords samples to come from. Any ideas on how to solve this would be welcome.